# Pullback of a reduced closed subscheme along an étale morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ any $Y$ be reduced schemes of finite type over a field and $W\subseteq Y$ a closed reduced subscheme.

1. What is an example of such $X$ and $Y$ and $W$ and of a morphism $f:X\to Y$ such that the closed subscheme $X\times_Y W\subseteq X$ is not reduced?
2. Is there such an example for $f:X\to Y$ étale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. This even fails when $W$ is the spectrum of a field. Take any ramified morphism (such as $\mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1, t \mapsto t^2$, the fiber at $0$ is the spectrum of $k[t]/(t^2)$).
2. I don't think so. Since $X \times_Y W \to W$ is étale, it suffices to remark that for an étale morphism of local noetherian schemes $X \to Y$: If $Y$ is reduced, then also $X$ is reduced. This follows from Proposition 19.5 in [Stacks project, etale morphisms](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/etale.pdf).

Comment: Dear @Martin Brandenburg, yes, thatnk you for answering the first point, this is a nice and easy example. Do you have an argument for 2.?